# How can I do a pause of 2Hz in a clock in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, clock, intel-fpga

I'm tecnically new in VHDL, and I need to do a pause of 2Hz or 0.5Hz in VHDL program for a counter project.

On the other hand, i have the following code:

```
architecture behavior of Counter is
signal q: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin
process(clock, choose)
  begin

    if clear = '1' then
        q <= q - q;
    else
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            -- when choose is '1', the process if for increment
            if(choose = '1') then
                case incodec is           
                    when "001" => q <= q + 1;
                    when "011" => q <= q + 10;
                    when "111" => q <= q + 11;
                    when others => q <= q;
                end case;
            -- when choose is '0', the process if for decrement
            elsif choose = '0' then
                case incodec is           
                    when "001" => q <= q - 1;
                    when "011" => q <= q - 10;
                    when "111" => q <= q - 11;
                    when others => q <= q;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    case q(7 downto 4) is
                                  --  6543210
        when "0000" => hex7 <= "1000000"; --0
        when "0001" => hex7 <= "1111001"; --1
        when "0010" => hex7 <= "0100100"; --2
        when "0011" => hex7 <= "0110000"; --3
        when "0100" => hex7 <= "0011001"; --4
        when "0101" => hex7 <= "0010010"; --5
        when "0110" => hex7 <= "0000010"; --6
        when "0111" => hex7 <= "1111000"; --7
        when "1000" => hex7 <= "0000000"; --8
        when "1001" => hex7 <= "0010000"; --9
        when "1010" => hex7 <= "0001000"; --10/A
        when "1011" => hex7 <= "0000011"; --11/B/b
        when "1100" => hex7 <= "1000110"; --12/C
        when "1101" => hex7 <= "0100001"; --13/D/d
        when "1110" => hex7 <= "0000110"; --14/E
        when "1111" => hex7 <= "0001110"; --15/F
        when others => hex7 <= "0111111"; -- -
    end case;

    case q(3 downto 0) is
                                  --  6543210
        when "0000" => hex6 <= "1000000"; --0
        when "0001" => hex6 <= "1111001"; --1
        when "0010" => hex6 <= "0100100"; --2
        when "0011" => hex6 <= "0110000"; --3
        when "0100" => hex6 <= "0011001"; --4
        when "0101" => hex6 <= "0010010"; --5
        when "0110" => hex6 <= "0000010"; --6
        when "0111" => hex6 <= "1111000"; --7
        when "1000" => hex6 <= "0000000"; --8
        when "1001" => hex6 <= "0010000"; --9
        when "1010" => hex6 <= "0001000"; --10/A
        when "1011" => hex6 <= "0000011"; --11/B/b
        when "1100" => hex6 <= "1000110"; --12/C
        when "1101" => hex6 <= "0100001"; --13/D/d
        when "1110" => hex6 <= "0000110"; --14/E
        when "1111" => hex6 <= "0001110"; --15/F
        when others => hex6 <= "0111111"; -- -
    end case;
end behavior
```

When the program compile show the following error:

> Error (10818): Can't infer register for "q[0]" at Counter.vhd(28) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
>   I don't know what is means

Help me please :(

Comment: Really are 11 errors like these.

Comment: At first, please show us the complete code, because there error is probably outside of the shows code snippet. At second, why are there so many leading zeros in your incrementing numbers?  At third, you don't need to assign q to q in the others cases, because it's a clocked process, more ovr some synthesizers might get irritated by that coding style. Are you aware of that `00000011` is an integer literal of value 11 instead of a binary number of value 3?

Comment: How does you code about a pause relate to your code snippet? Pauses are not measured in Hertz, but in seconds, because it's a time and not a frequency.

Comment: The problem with the `other` cases is because when I compile the project, show me this error: `Error (10313): VHDL Case Statement error at Counter.vhd(29): Case Statement choices must cover all possible values of expression
`

Comment: Are you aware of that 00000011 is an integer literal of value 11 instead of a binary number of value 3? No, I don't know, but i believe this works equal because `q` is a binary digit. I think so.

Comment: Yes, others must be present, but this doesn't mean that you need `q <= q;` A type on the left-hand-side of an operation has no effect on the interpretation of literals on the right-hand-side in an binary operation.

Comment: One question per topic please. You are both asking about the "pause" and asking us to debug your code here.

Comment: You accepted the answer, but this was not yet about your original question. It was just about bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your code contains multiple mistakes:**

- Don't use the Synopsys packages to do arithmetic operations.
  Use package `numeric_std` and types `signed` and/or `unsigned` instead.
- `q` represents state and will be synthesized as flip-flops.
  So on an FPGA technology, initialize them: `:= (others => '0')`
- `clear` is an asynchronous signal, so list it in the sensitivity list.
- `choose` is a synchronous signal, so don't list it in the sensitivity list.
- When you want to add numbers 1,2,3 then use proper integer literals or specify your literal explicitly as binary. The default is decimal.
- Using variables will shorten your code by eliminating duplication.
- Clearing `q` should be done by assigning all zeros with an aggregate: `(others => '0')`.
- A for loop and another variable can further reduce your code and remove another big section of duplicated code.
- User variable `hex` will also remove an additional register stage, that is most likely not intended by most designers.
- You commented you segment names of the 7-segment display `6543210`, but segments are usually named `GFEDCBA`.
- You should put your 7-segment decoder into a separate entity or function to increase reuseability.
- Your 7-segment display code is low-active, but designers should write high-active code. The low-activeness is due to the board or display design and not the responsibility of the decoder. Inversion can be done when assigning `hex` to `hex7`.

**Here is the improved code:**

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use     IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity Counter is
    -- ...
end entity;


architecture behavior of Counter is
    signal q : unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process(clock, clear)
        variable decoded : positive;
        variable hex     : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
    begin
        case incodec is           
            when "001" =>  decoded := 1;
            when "011" =>  decoded := 2;
            when "111" =>  decoded := 3;
            when others => decoded := 0;
        end case;

        if clear = '1' then
            q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if(choose = '1') then     -- when choose is '1', the process if for increment
                q <= q + decoded;
            elsif (choose = '0') then -- when choose is '0', the process if for decrement
                q <= q - decoded;
            end if;
        end if;

        for i in 0 to 1 loop
            case q(i*4+7 downto i*4) is            --  6543210
                when "0000" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "1000000"; --0
                when "0001" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "1111001"; --1
                when "0010" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0100100"; --2
                when "0011" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0110000"; --3
                when "0100" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0011001"; --4
                when "0101" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0010010"; --5
                when "0110" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0000010"; --6
                when "0111" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "1111000"; --7
                when "1000" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0000000"; --8
                when "1001" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0010000"; --9
                when "1010" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0001000"; --10/A
                when "1011" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0000011"; --11/b
                when "1100" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "1000110"; --12/C
                when "1101" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0100001"; --13/d
                when "1110" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0000110"; --14/E
                when "1111" => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0001110"; --15/F
                when others => hex(i*7+6 downto i*7) := "0111111"; -- -
            end case;
        end loop;

        hex7 <= hex(13 downto 7);
        hex6 <= hex(6 downto 0);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: How does this answer *How can I do a pause of 2Hz in a clock in VHDL?*

Comment: @user1155120 While writing part 1 of the answer to get his code working, I solve his implicit question about a state that was not hold outside if rising edge. I'm still hoping for an edit to write part two, when he clarifies his question.